# How to upload/store "large" image url(generated from canvas.toDataUrl()) to node js or express js or cloudinary?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, canvas, cloudinary

I'm doing a small project using the React js, and my server is running with the express and node js with mongodb database.

For the smaller url I'm able to communicate with the server as normal. But as I upload a larger url(genrated from canvas.todataurl()) I'm unable to send the data to the server. It throws 413 payload too large error.
My purpose is to generate image url from canvas, and that image url is send to cloudinary or mongodb database so that If requires in future I can take it from there. I already added bodyparse with set limit, still the error persists.

I used a event handler button, upon clicking on it image file is download simultaneously that image url is stored in either mongodb database or cloudinary. My url is generated from canvas(canvas.todataurl()), this url is too large and due to this payload too large or 413 error is persists.

downhandler where generating url from canvas and also uploading to cloudinary is performed:-

const handleDownload = () => {

```
if (canvasRef) {
  
  const imageData = localStorage.getItem("certificate-image");

  if (imageData) {
   
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = imageData;
    link.download = "certificate.png";
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);

    //Original fetch if new not work

  fetch(`http://localhost:1200/update/${id}`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body:imageData,
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
      console.log("resbase updated successfully:", res);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error updating database:", error);
    });

  //Original fetch if new not work

  
  } else {
    console.error("No image data found in localStorage.");
  }
}
```

};

I can undestand the terms of cloudinary, but the point is what to do when image url is too large. I am pasting 2 image url please check it will help you to understand.

https://github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com/103572350/292864250-e2b1c4f4-ef1d-47a2-9a66-bbbd1828eb4c.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20231226%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231226T115204Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=f16716ae97c5963d06076147709078196d8d4a52d3bf18e2b1dcd4675df41595&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=103572350&key_id=0&repo_id=497514745

https://github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com/103572350/292864245-074df1ff-2d28-4eb8-a73e-f47a06841672.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20231226%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231226T115134Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=c7a4e377ba825687e2f8b3dc9c155721864402b3633ded41d64983e4b32ee867&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=103572350&key_id=0&repo_id=497514745

Comment: You forgot to post your code

Comment: @possum, I am attempting to save a URL in Cloudinary through a POST request using Postman. However, I am encountering an issue where the URL is too large, resulting in a 'payload is too large' error. I am seeking guidance on how to overcome this limitation and successfully store the lengthy URL in Cloudinary through the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

When uploading files to Cloudinary, the maximum size of the request body can be 100MB. Any request that is larger than this would receive the 413 error you're seeing. To upload files larger than 100MB, these need to be sent in chunks.

You can use Cloudinary SDK, please check to make sure you are using the `upload_large` method for your uploads instead of the regular upload method. The upload_large method should be used for all files >100MB as it splits the file and uploads it in parts automatically for you.

Below I'm also including a sample JSFiddle of chunked uploads implemented within JS that you can use -
https://jsfiddle.net/leptians/hLajmbpf/

Comment: please check above two urls, the context I want to explain.

Comment: As I explained, you should upload in chunks. Cloudinary has SDKs that support using the upload_large method.